# OS X 10.9 Redistributable?

Tags: mac, data-transfer, macos

I work in an Apple-only office environment with ~40 Macs. Is it possible for me to download an OS X 10.9 redistributable so that we're not downloading 5+ GB continually over our ADSL link ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is.

You can download it once and then distribute it over an external Harddrive, an USB Flash Drive or your network. The package is called `Install OS X Mavericks.app` and you will find it in the directory `/Applications`.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.**

The Mavericks installer downloads as an app called **Install OS X Mavericks**, which gets installed in your /Applications folder. If you copy that to a USB drive, you can take it around and copy it to each one of your computers.

However, be careful – normally, the installation process deletes the app once it's done. You need to copy it from a machine *before* you install Mavericks on it.

Even better, you could create a bootable Mavericks install disk on a USB drive (like the old CDs that Apple used to ship <- remember those? :P). There are plenty of instructions around the web; [Macworld](http://www.macworld.com/article/2056561/how-to-make-a-bootable-mavericks-install-drive.html) and [Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2013/10/how-to-make-your-own-bootable-os-x-10-9-mavericks-usb-install-drive/) both seem to have particularly good ones.

---

One of the new features of Mavericks Server is designed to alleviate this burden. Quoting from Apple’s [product page](http://www.apple.com/uk/osx/server/features/):

> Caching Server makes it faster than ever to download apps to every Mac on your network running OS X Mountain Lion v10.8.2 or later. When a user on your network downloads new software from the Mac App Store, a copy is automatically stored on your server. So the next time other users on your network update or download that same software, they're actually accessing it from inside the network.

If all of your machines are already in Mountain Lion, then you might be able to install Mavericks Server once, then push the update out this way. That saves you carrying around a USB drive, and is a more future-proof solution.

However, I’ve not used Mavericks Server yet, so I can’t attest to the quality of this feature.

Answer (score 0):

And with [CCC](http://www.bombich.com/) (carbon copy cloner) you can make a bootable volume (SD CARD, USB…).